# Mobile web version the site now doesn't allow me to up vote, down vote, accept answer

Tags: support

I'm using opera mini 4.3 on a Nokia 5000d. I just realised today that i can't perform the functions listed above. I could do all those things previously using the same device and browser. Is it a bug or am i doing something wrong?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Opera Mini is not in our supported browser list, for a variety of reasons.

A few more details here:

[Functionality regression on Opera Mini](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/102010/functionality-regression-on-opera-mini)

Comment: ok thanks for the answer